# how to maintain the keys in TransformDict in python

Tags: python-3.x

https://github.com/fluentpython/example-code/blob/master/03-dict-set/transformdict.py

I see the demo:
'''Dictionary that calls a transformation function when looking
    up keys, but preserves the original keys.

```
>>> d = TransformDict(str.lower)
>>> d['Foo'] = 5
>>> d['foo'] == d['FOO'] == d['Foo'] == 5
True
>>> set(d.keys())
{'Foo'}
'''
```

but , i dont know the object how to maintain the keys.
thanks

I really want to ask how the keys method works

Comment: It's a question you could answer yourself by reading the source code.

Comment: can you tell me which souce code should i read? thanks

Comment: https://github.com/fluentpython/example-code/blob/master/03-dict-set/transformdict.py

Comment: but, I still dont understand how the keys method works...

Answer (score 0):

It keeps 2 dictionaries, 1 for the keys and one for the values see getitem in line 51:

```
def getitem(self, key):
    'D.getitem(key) -> (stored key, value)'
    transformed = self._transform(key)
    original = self._original[transformed] # original keys!
    value = self._data[transformed] # values!
    return original, value
```

Comment: I understand this。
but i dont know how d.keys() work,
why it reads from _original dict not reads from the keys of _data dict .
Thank you very much for your answer

I look forward to your answer